# Is there a way to pipe binary stream to remote server using ssh and Python?

Tags: python-2.7, ssh

NOTE: not interested in any modules like Pramiko

I'm trying to save some binary data on remote server without creating local file.

As a test I read from file but later I'm replacing it with data feed:

```
ps = subprocess.Popen(['cat', "/delta/ftp/GSM.PRICINT_TBL.dmp"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Next step I want to ssh data to remote server

```
ssh = subprocess.Popen(["ssh", '-XC', '-c', 'blowfish-cbc,arcfour', 'deltadmin@archiveserver', 'echo - >/tmp/test.log'],
                                shell=False,
                                stdin = ps.stdout,
                                stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        result = ssh.stdout.readlines()
        if result == []:
            error = ssh.stderr.readlines()
            print >>sys.stderr, "ERROR: %s" % error
        else:
            print result
```

I use '-' so `cat` can accept standard input.
Expected result is data in `/tmp/test.log` but i see only

> '-\n'

Any idea how to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it:

```
echo 'test'|ssh -XC -c blowfish-cbc,arcfour bicadmin@nitarchive -T 'gzip - >/tmp/test.gz'
```

then on remote server:

```
 zcat /tmp/test.gz
test
```

For `cat` we need space after redirect:

```
cat - > /tmp/test.txt
```